# Increment value in F#

Tags: f#

Maybe it's too simple thing to do, but I can't find any answer in the web
I'm try to Increment value in F# (like `count++` in C#).
I don't want to use "mutable" option,
I'm just want to see an example, who Increment function in F# should look like.
And how do I use it.

Comment: Do you mean `let f x = x + 1`

Comment: But i can't use: count = f count

Comment: http://jprajavel.blogspot.nl/2011/11/i-kind-of-functionality-in-f.html first hit on google for `i++ in F#`

Answer (score 28):

The idea of "incrementing a value" in the same sense as in C++ only makes sense when you're working with mutable values or when you're using a mutable reference cell (essentially a simple object that stores a mutable value). If you have a mutable reference cell, you can use `incr` function:

```
let count = ref 0
incr count
```

If you use a mutable variable, then there is no built-in function for this and you need to write `count + 1`:

```
let mutable count = 0
count <- count + 1
```

If you're writing code using immutable values, then you will generally just write `count + 1` and then pass the result to some function (or somewhere else - this depends on the specific case). For example, to calculate the length of an F# list, you would write:

```
let rec length list =
  match list with 
  | [] -> 0
  | _::tail -> 1 + (length tail)
```

In this example, the expression `1 + (...)` is the code corresponding to `i++` in a C++ code that iterates over a list and computes its length. The result of the expression is not assigned to a new variable, because it is returned directly as a result of the `length` function.

**EDIT** Parameters of functions are immutable meaning that you cannot change their values. As mentioned by Lee, you can use variable shadowing to hide the old value with a new one - but note that this only has a local effect (it is like defining a new variable with different name to store the new value). For example:

```
let rec length list count =
  match list with 
  | [] -> count
  | _::tail -> 
     let count = count + 1 // Variable shadowing used here
     length tail count
```

You cannot write a function to simplify the line `let count = count + 1` and as mentioned above, this is equivalent to writing `let newCount = count + 1` and then using `newCount` on the last line.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but I want to write a function that take  "count" as parameter and then (in function body) it's increment it how can I do that?

Comment: @cheziHoyzer See edit - but note that the functional approach is to use immutable values, so you cannot "increment" a local variable (be it a variable or function parameter) unless it is mutable.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Doesn't `incr x` only work when `x` is a 32-bit integer?

Answer (score 5):

You can't simulate a postincrement operator but you can do preincrement

```
let inline (+=) (x : byref<_>) y = x <- x + y

let mutable a = 0
&a += 1
```

or

```
let inline incv (x : byref<_>) = x <- x + LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne; x

let mutable b = 0
incv &b
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use mutable then you can't really do a destructive update like `++` is in C#. You could shadow a variable with a new one with the same name e.g.

```
let x = 4;
let x = x + 1 in (x+4)  //returns 8
```

although you couldn't write this as a function.

EDIT: If do want to use mutable variables then you can create a function which modifies a [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx):

```
let increment (ir: int ref) = ir := !ir + 1
```

You can then use it as

```
let i = ref 1
increment i
let iv = !i    //iv contains 2
```

As Tomas points out in his answer, this function already exists and is called `incr`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but I want to write a function that take "count" as parameter and then (in function body) it's increment it (if I use mutable), how can I do that (who the function declaration should look like?)

Comment: It would be nicer to make this version generic so it can handle int64 in addition to int32