# Counters in functional programming

Tags: list, f#, pattern-matching

I built a simple function that, given a list, returns a list of lists. Each single list have to be ordered. 
E.g.:

```
 subOrd [4;4;10;20;5;30;6;10]      --> [[4;4;10;20];[5;30];[6;10]]
 subOrd [5;6;4;3;2;1]              --> [[5;6];[4];[3];[2];[1]]
```

I this is my present solution, it works pretty well, except for a detail:

```
let rec subOrd (l1: int list) :int list list =
    let rec aux2 (l2: int list) (l3: int list) :int list=
        match l2 with
        | []                                ->  []
        | [x]                               ->  [x]
        | x0::(x1::_ as xs) when x0 > x1    ->  x0::l3
        | x0::(x1::_ as xs) when x0 <= x1   ->  (x0::l3)@(aux xs l3)
    match l1 with
    | []                ->  []
    | x::xs             ->  (aux2 l1 [])::subOrd xs
```

It repeats the operation for every `xs` in the last match. By feeding to the function the list `a4`, I get:

```
let a4 = [1; 3; 4; 7; 5; 6]
val it : int list list = [[1; 3; 4; 7]; [3; 4; 7]; [4; 7]; [7]; [5; 6]; [6]]
```

With C, I think I will index the array with an incremented counter. Conceptually, something such as `xs.[i]`. I found information on how to [Increment value in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212133/increment-value-in-f), but I am not sure about the best approach to face this problem functionally.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: you definitely don't need any counters or indexing here.

Comment: this looks to me like a code kata or coursework exercise, so I'm not sure how much I should give away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a counter and processing the list left-to-right, you could use `List.foldBack` to process it right-to-left e.g.

```
let subOrd l =
    let acc x = function
    | [] -> [[x]]
    | (((y::_) as ys) :: ls) -> 
        if x <= y then ((x::ys)::ls)
        else [x]::ys::ls
    | _ -> failwith "Should never happen!"

    List.foldBack acc l []
```

Comment: I did not think of such an approach. It is really interesting, thanks! I am going for a little of practice.

Comment: @Worice this is of course a good solution, but it also makes at least two conceptual jumps from what you started with. First approach would be to use direct recursion with two accumulators, then a `fold`, finally a `foldback`. Looking at them in order might make it easier to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of give-aways: Tail-recursion, conciseness, abstraction and genericity.

#### Tail-recursion

Having left-over work for processing after the return from repeated recursion is always a sub-optimal approach. It precludes the tail-call compiler optimization, whereby the recursive call is in effect compiled into a goto instructiuon. The stack will come under undue pressure with all those return adresses of the work still to be done and will eventually overflow.
An accumulator passed as an additional argument to the function solves this problem, as it will carry the result of the processing now done before the recursive call. In this case, it may even double as state containing the previous element. And yes, the result is now in the wrong order, but there's nothing wrong with reversing it again.

#### Conciseness

Try to formulate the logic in the simplest way possible: I want to divide a list into chunks according to the result of a comparison function applied to pairs of consecutive elements. This will require two match expressions, with a third one for the "no more elements, we're done" case.

#### Abstraction and genericity

Do not restrict yourself to a hard-coded use case eg. *comparion of ints by greater-equal*. You may need similiar functionality for other scenarions involving other conditions or other data types. Having the basic functionality already ironed out will enable profitable code re-use.

```
let chunkWhile p xs =
    let rec aux = function
    | (y::_) as ys::yss, x::xs when p x y -> aux ((x::ys)::yss, xs)
    | yss, x::xs -> aux ([x]::yss, xs)
    | yss, [] -> List.rev <| List.map List.rev yss
    aux ([], xs)

[4;4;10;20;5;30;6;10]
|> chunkWhile (>=)
// val it : int list list = [[4; 4; 10; 20]; [5; 30]; [6; 10]]
```

Deconstruct the accumulator to retrieve the element of the previous iteration and decide by passing the current and previous element to a predicate function. If the condition holds, prepend current element to the current chunk, which is the first element of the accumulator. Otherwise, as long as there are elements to process, create a new singleton list and prepend that to the accumulator. If there are no more elements, reverse all sub-lists in the accumulator and return them in reversed order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!