# Functional increment

Tags: f#

I am working on a simple function that should, given `x`, return a tuple `(y, z)` such that `y <= abs(5) + z * 10 = x`, where `z` the smallest possible value.

In C, I would loop over `z++` and `y++`, until their sum matches `x`.

Currently, I am trying to solve this problem functionally. Please consider the following example:

```
let foo x =
    let rec aux (y, z, q) =
        match (y + z * 10) with
        q       -> (y, z)
        |_      -> aux(y + 1, z + 1, q)    //How to correctly set the increments?
     aux(0, 0, x)
```

This approach always returns `(0, 0)`, no matter what. I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212133/increment-value-in-f), while thinking a solution. I am aware that mutable variables should be avoided, and that is what I do. Unfortunately, I am afraid I missed the point, somewhere, thus I am approaching the problem from the wrong side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're introducing a new `q` binding for the result of the expression evaluated in your first case match rather than comparing against it. What you want is something like this:

```
match (y + z * 10) with
| r when r = q -> (y, z)
| _ -> aux(y + 1, z + 1, q)
```

Answer (score 1):

In F# you are generally either within a value expression or a pattern matching expression. When you do this:

```
match (y + z * 10) with
q       -> (y, z)
```

You're effectively saying: "Calculate `y + z * 10` and then always assign the result to a new variable `q`, ignore this new variable and return `(y, z)`". This is because `q` is written in a pattern matching expression as it's just after `with`.

This is also why you're getting a warning on the next line saying "This rule will never by matched". This is a very common misunderstanding when people are learning F#.

You're not really making use of pattern matching at all when you do this. So I would recommend using an `if` expression instead:

```
        if y + z * 10 = q
        then (y, z)
        else aux (y + 1, z + 1, q)
```

This is actually equivalent to using the ternary operators `?` and `:` in C because it's an expression, not a statement, but it reads more clearly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, it helped me to make clearer the concept.